# Filtering a ComboBox in aPowershell form

Tags: forms, powershell, combobox

This works to populate my combobox:

```
$arrUsers = @{}
Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=Users DT,DC=company,DC=co' -Filter * | `
sort -Property SurName, GivenName | %{
    if ($_.SurName -AND $_.GivenName){
        $arrUsers.Add("$($_.SurName), $($_.GivenName)", $($_.DistinguishedName))
    }
}

$arrUsers.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property name | %{
    $objUsersDataTableRow = $objUsersDataTable.NewRow()
    $objUsersDataTableRow.Text = $_.Key
    $objUsersDataTableRow.Value = $_.Value
    $objUsersDataTable.Rows.Add($objUsersDataTableRow)
} 

$objComboBoxUsers.ValueMember = "Value"
$objComboBoxUsers.DisplayMember = "Text"
$objComboBoxUsers.Datasource = $objUsersDataTable
$objComboBoxUsers.SelectedItem = $objComboBoxUsers.Items[0]
```

This filter that I am dynamically adding later isn't working correctly:

```
$objComboBoxUsers.Datasource = $objUsersDataTable | where{$_.Text -match $FilterText}
```

All the combo box items get replaced with **System.Data.DataRow**.

I want to understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had an oversimplified understanding of datasources.

This worked instead:

```
$objUsersDataTable.defaultview.rowfilter = "Text like '%$($FilterText)%'"
$objComboBoxUsers.Datasource = $objUsersDataTable
```